# Best language for multiple platform software

Tags: android, ios, windows, web, multiplatform

This time I'm trying to make a software that can be used on iOs, Android, as standalone software, as a web app, and I want to know if there is a way to make a base code in one language and with little effort and minimum changes use it to compile it for all the platforms. I was thinking in c++, but is there a better option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I think a framework is a good answer I want to do a survey engine, that is why I thinking to do it with c++ or another language.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap gets you three out of four http://phonegap.com/

Answer (score 1):

Seems rather obvious to point out, but you **Adobe Air** can do each item in your list using the same code.  The language behind it is Actionscript and is object oriented.  From the same code, you can output Flash for web, Android apps, iOs apps, a standalone Air application for desktops.  You can develop in Air using a Mac or PC.

(If you are using a PC to create apps, for uploading to iTunes, you need a Mac, but you can rent a virtual Mac from http://www.macincloud.com, which works on a PC.  You will have to use the Mac to create your certificates and upload the IPA file onto iTunes, but it works perfectly without the expense of buying a Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider going as a service on the web. Otherwise, c# is a good all way to go. There are sites that will alter different sources of code to different outputs.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile also good framework for multiple mobile platforms. [link to website](http://jquerymobile.com/). We are using this for same purpose. So far everything good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned this yet, but [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) should be your go-to for cross-platform app creation.  Nominally, Unity is for cross-platform game development, but its expansive libraries allow for robust general-purpose program development.  Unity provides you with great tools for building UIs, and it has an active community of developers.

Comment: But Unity is eye-scratchingly expensive for professional apps.

Answer (score 0):

Using C# will get you Android, iOS and Windows Phone if those are key platforms for you. Using Mono / Xamarin you can develop apps in C# / .NET.